# What ARN for DynamoDB policy generator

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I've created a table called 'laptops'on Amazon DynamoDB. I want to create a policy that allows all actions for all my dynamoDB table. What should I put in the Amazon Resource Name (ARN) in the policy generator?

`arn:aws:dynamodb:*` -- doesn't work

`arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:table/folders` -- doesn't work either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact policy would be:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "dynamodb:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:here_goes_your_account_id:table/laptops"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
```

You were missing your account id between the region and "table". And if you want that policy to apply to all your DynamoDB tables, replace laptops for '*'.